# Python getattr() member or function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Python's getattr() to extract data out of a number of objects that I got from various APIs that I do not control. My idea was to go through a list of hetrogenous objects and try to getattr() on them until I pull out everything that I need.

So I'm doing one of these:

```
if hasattr(o, required_field):
    value = getattr(o, required_field)
    result.append([required_field, value])
    print 'found field', field, 'for value', value
```

My problem is sometimes the objects I'm dealing with have object.data() and sometiems object.data to pull stuff out. Sometimes these objects are actually generators.

So once in a while I'd get something like this:

```
found field ValueOfRisk for value
CellBM:<Instrument:/limbo/WLA_YdgjTdK1XA2qOlm8cQ==>.ValueOfRisk>
```

Question: is there a way that I can say 'access the data member when it's a data member, or call a function when it's a function' to take the value out of these things? Seems like this should be easy with Python but I can't find it.

Comment: Perhaps the `callable` function is what you're looking for?  It'll tell you whether you can call the attribute.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty Isn't callable deprecated?  Edit: Guess not.  Saw a post to that effect, but the official 2.7 documentation does not say so.

Comment: Thanks for the good and quick replies guys, I learned from your answers and got my stuff working. Can only pick one 'right' one though :(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if hasattr(value, '__call__'):
    value = value()
```

alternate:

```
if callable(value):
    value = value()
```

also:

```
import types
if isinstance(value, types.GeneratorType):
    # Handle generator case
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`callable`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#callable) function:

```
if hasattr(o, required_field):
    v = getattr(o, required_field):
    if not callable(v):
        print "found field", required_value, "for value", v
```

In Python 3, use `isinstance(obj, collections.Callable)` (after `import collections`, of course).  Also, it appears `callable` was added back in Python 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a call to the method would be safe:

```
methods = []
properties = []

if hasattr(o,required_field):
  value = getattr(o,required_field)
  try:
     #see if this value is callable
     value()
     methods.append(value)
  except TypeError:
     #property is not a method
     properties.append(value)
```

Comment: This presumes you are happy to call it there, of course. It could have side-effects that mean this isn't a viable option.

Comment: @Lattyware Yah, I will edit to denote that limitation... just was thinking of duck-typing.  I've actually learned some new approaches from the other answers, good question!

Comment: If you do want to call it at the time, this is the optimal solution - *ask for forgiveness, not permission*.